# Query filter isn't returning object

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I'm trying to get this audience object, that currently has its date set to 30/07/2021 (tomorrow), using the following querysets:

```
print("qset 1:",Audience.objects.filter(start_date__year=self.year, start_date__month=self.month))
print("qset 2:",Audience.objects.filter(start_date__year=self.year, start_date__month=self.month, lawyer=lawyer))
```

But it returns nothing. So I decided to try and check manually with those...

```
aud=Audience.objects.get(id=3)

print("lawyer:",lawyer,"date",self.month,self.year,aud.start_date.month,aud.start_date.year)
if aud.start_date.month == self.month:
    print("month")
if aud.start_date.year == self.year:
    print("year")
```

... and got the return I was expecting on the console

```
lawyer: marcosv1 date 7 2021 7 2021
month
year
qset 1: <QuerySet []>
qset 2: <QuerySet []>
qset 3: <QuerySet []>
```

Can anyone identify the issue on this? I've spent several hours, with nothing coming to mind.

Comment: probably due to timezone issues. see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/timezones/ for more information.

Comment: Can you print `start_date`?

Comment: @bdbd start_date: 2021-07-30 05:07:00+00:00

Comment: @Abhyudai thanks for the suggestion, but I've set the following variables:

```TIME_ZONE = 'America/Bahia'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True```

Comment: you will have to change your time and date objects to timezone aware before filtering them on database values, since you probably wouldn't have changed the timezone on the database.